# Needs help on python web application with many to many relationship

Tags: python

I am trying to make a web application in which there are 2 models user and company. A user can access any number of companies. many to many relationship between user and company. there is one autogenerated number which is used for application purpose. this autonumber is based on company. My concept in mind is that when a user login to the application there should be a list of companies that he has access. he select the company which ever he wants and proceed to application. this company should be the active company for that user. based this active company the autonumber generated. for eg : if company A selected then A0001.
i am using flask framework
Please advice how to achive this.

Comment: yes many-to-many is correct.  I don't see any problems. keep going.

Comment: yes the relationships are okey. and while login the companies also displayed. but after that i got stucked . means i need autogenerated numbers for active company. how to store the active company(selected company) . using session? or is there any better idea. is there any way to store this to an attribute g.user as g.user.active_company?

Comment: session is fine.  store the auto generated number (I think this is a company id) in the session.  Another option is cookie but you have to either validate the company id or encrypt the company id so the user can't alter the id, and gain unauthorized access to other companies.

Comment: Thanks Kenji. Am trying with session